# Socketed FTP Client Log on issue

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp, solaris

*EDITED*

I'm making a C++ program for connecting to my school's FTP server and allowing me to get files from my account. Nothing to complex, BUT I keep running into the 530 return code. I start by establishing the socket on port 21 (FTP command port) and sending `USER xxxxx` then I get a 220 code response saying I'm connected to 111.111.111, next I will send the user command `PASS xxxxx`, but the password isn't being accepted and I get a 331 code

Here's the terminal from running the code below:

```
>./FTP
FTP: USER xxxxx
FTP: 220 csci2.stcloudstate.edu FTP server ready.
FTP: PASS xxxxx
FTP: 331 Password required for xxxxx.
 ready.
FTP: PASS xxxxx
FTP: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ready.
>
```

I'm thinking I don't have the correct formatting for my commands, so below is the code If anyone sees where my user/password input is going wrong.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
        //variables
    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
    int Res;
    char buff[60];
    char UserFeed[30];
    int SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    string FTPread;
    string FtpCommand;
        ...
    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof(stSockAddr)); 
    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(21);
        ...

    //Enter USER xxxxxx
    cout<<"FTP: ";
    fgets(UserFeed,30,stdin);
    write(SocketFD, UserFeed, strnln(UserFeed));
    recv(SocketFD,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    cout<<"FTP: "<<buff;

    //Enter PASS xxxxxxxx
    cout<<"FTP: ";
    fgets(UserFeed,30,stdin);
    write(SocketFD, UserFeed, strnln(UserFeed));
    recv(SocketFD,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    cout<<"FTP: "<<buff;
        ...
}
```

*NOTES: this is using berkeley sockets, FTP will be passive mode(hence no data connection yet), and this is coded/compiled/run from a solaris system on the same network as the FTP server.

Comment: Are you able to log in by `telnet 111.111.111 21` and typing out the `USER xxxx` and `PASS xxxx` commands directly?

Comment: Also, it seems a little suspicious that you're reading up to 30 characters with `fgets`, but the buffer you're reading into is only 25 characters long...  Furthermore, you should be sending only as many characters as you read (eg. `strlen(UserFeed)`), not `sizeof(UserFeed)`.

Comment: And finally, why are you writing the command `ftp xxx.xxx.xxx` to the socket?  Once you've opened the socket, you should just be transmitting FTP protocol commands over the socket.

Comment: Joe, yes to the telnet question, and typo for the 25 and 30 mix-match. I will try to just send the USER info instead of the ftp xxx.xxx.xxx stuff to see. Will revise code in question

Comment: Now in your transcript it looks like you may be sending PASS twice.   When you deleted the `ftp xxx.xxx.xxx` command line, you also deleted the `recv()` that was receiving the 220 welcome message.  You might put that back, so the commands and responses line up better.  If you really are sending `PASS` twice accidentally, that may be your only remaining problem.

Comment: Those lines are user input. and it doesnt matter how many times I want to send it, if the 1st time is never recognised. Thats just to show that the pass doesn't get accepted even on multiple attempts

Comment: Using strlen() is the solution, I remember I used to use sizeof() but that gave me errors.